# Change in data bound property is not propagating upwards

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I have nested custom elements which interact with each other.

```
<dom-module id="dom-element">   
  <template>
    <custom-element bindingTest="{{found}}"></custom-element>
  </template>  
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "dom-element",
      properties: {
        found: {
          type:String,
          value:"4"
        }
      },
      ready: function() {
        this.addEventListener("found-changed", this.foundChanged);
      },
      foundChanged:function(e){
        console.log("found changed");
      }  
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Child custom element:

```
<dom-module id="custom-element">
  <template>
    <button on-click="toParent">Send to parent</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "custom-element",
      properties:{
        bindingTest: {
          type: String, 
          notify: true
        }
      },
      toParent: function () {
        this.bindingTest = "change of binding test"
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

If I understood correctly, this.bindingTest = "change of binding test" should notify parent custom element and "found" parameter should become equal to "change of binding test" String, that is, toParent function has to be called, but it isn't being called for some reason. How do I notify parent when bindingTest changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

The problem here is that you are accessing the `bindingTest` property of the child element incorrectly. From the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping)

> In order to configure camel-case properties of elements using attributes, dash- case should be used in the attribute name.

So you will need to change your `custom-element` tag to be:

```
<custom-element binding-test="{{found}}"></custom-element>
```

I've set up a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fr81a8Y9bpRSUbIJnKt2?p=preview) for you to look at.

Comment: uh, i think OP meant that the {{found}} value in parent wasn't being changed by the toParent function, instead of the event/console.log not being called.

Comment: yeap, that's what I meant. If I log this.found in foundChanged(), it still shows "4" instead of "change of binding test"

Comment: Thanks. Gotta get used to it. I got you but the plunker link isn't opening. You might want to fix it for future reference for others

Comment: I think the site is currently down unfortunately!